# Problems with scripting postgreSQL commands

Tags: postgresql

Is there any possibility to dump the results of PostgreSQL commands directly on a txt/csv file ? i am talking about commands not queries, commands such as 
- SHOW ssl;
- SHOW log_connections;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `psql` client for that.

```
\f ','
\a
\o <myoutputfile>
SHOW ssl;
\q
```

Or with command line options:

```
psql -t -A -F"," -c "SHOW ssl" > "<myoutputfile>"
```

Comment: The 1st method works fine .. but i like the 2nd one better to script using batch .. but i couldn't force the login/connection credentials into the script .. any ideas @Thomas ?

Comment: You can provide much of the information, including password, as environment variables to psql: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html